# get request url for spring boot-based web application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

I am trying to get a request URL. Here is my url.

http://localhost/app/product?id=0195AA7D26BE4A02944C14D3226F6EAC

I want to get "product?id=0195AA7D26BE4A02944C14D3226F6EAC". I can get the querystring with request.getQueryString(), but when I print out request.getRequestURI(), I am not getting it. I am getting the layout JSP file.

I am printing out like this to see which one works, but none of them works.

```
    out.println(request.getContextPath() + "<br>");
    out.println(request.getServletPath() + "<br>");
    out.println(request.getPathInfo() + "<br>");
    out.println(request.getRequestURI() + "<br>");
    out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString() + "<br>");
```

I am getting like this.

```
/app
/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/basicLayout.jsp
null
/app/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/basicLayout.jsp
http://localhost/app/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/basicLayout.jsp
```

Is there any spring mvc API which returns the request URI that I want to get?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a controller to process the request? Have you tried to get the request URL there? (I tested it with a small example and was able to get the request URL.)

Comment: No. I am doing it in jsp.